# How to start "limit" in Query Language backwards?

Tags: google-visualization

I want to visualize data from a `Google Spreadsheet` and I only want to show the last 60 entries. I tried it with:

```
setQuery('select A, D limit 60');
```

But it starts from the beginning not from the end in a reverse order. I also played around with `offset` but I would have to count the entries before that would make sense. Is there an easy way for that?

Comment: You have to use an `ORDER BY` clause to reverse the order of your results, then take the first 60.

Comment: Julian or @asgallant, mind tossing that in an answer as comments frequently get removed and the info gets lost? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @asgallent, the correct code is:

```
setQuery('select A, D ORDER BY A DESC limit 60');
```